# Best way to detect Docker container exit

Tags: docker

I have some remote servers running Docker images, and want them to "phone home" when the container stops, to alert me to check out the recent logs and figure out what caused the main process in the container to exit. What's the best way to do this? I could just drop the container's CMD/ENTRYPOINT into a wrapper script that does something like `./my_process || phone_home.sh`, but I imagine that won't handle actual Docker engine issues, like OOM or someone explicitly doing `docker stop my-container`.

Is there anything built in to Docker for this or am I better off with some custom sidecar "watcher" service that just constantly checks `docker ps` output?

Comment: Same question as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383574/docker-shutdown-hook-or-support-for-graceful-exit  ?

Comment: And even better advice: https://milesmaddox.com/1477944296/  (I think)