# Startup & Shutdown bash script strategy docker

Tags: docker

I have two bash scripts, first script `run.sh` is run a python file to create a subscription (using a hostname) google pub/sub also listen/subscribe with the subscription. I'm putting this into `entrypoint` option on docker compose, also try on command option as well

```
#!/bin/sh
python -u client.py 'project-id' 'receive' 'topic-name' "subsciber-$(hostname -f)"
```

docker compose

```
services:
  subscription:
      ....
      entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "/opt/subscription/scripts/run.sh"]
```

and another script `delete-subscriber.sh` is run a python script to delete subscription, I want this script run when I stop the container, is there any option on docker compose config instead of run manually using docker compose events (stop, kill etc)?

```
#!/bin/sh
python -u client.py 'project-id' 'delete' "subscriber-$(hostname -f)"
```

Here is `client.py`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  args = parser.parse_args()
  if args.command == 'receive':
     create_subscription(args.project, args.topic_name, args.subscription_name)
     receive_messages(args.project, args.subscription_name)
  elif args.command == 'delete':
     delete_subscription(args.project, args.subscription_name)
```

references :

- create a subscription https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/create-subscription#pubsub_create_pull_subscription-python
- receive message https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publish-receive-messages-client-library#python_1
- delete a subscription https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-delete-subscription#pubsub_delete_subscription-python

Comment: If worst comes to worst, the container orchestration sends a `kill -9` (aka. `SIGKILL`) to the process and that's that. In short: there is no way to guarantee that the shutdown script is executed. That said, while docker does not support any shutdown hooks, we can [`trap` signals within the container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383574/docker-shutdown-hook-or-support-for-graceful-exit). Notice that [`SIGKILL`cannot be `trap`ped](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker shutdown hook or support for graceful exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383574/docker-shutdown-hook-or-support-for-graceful-exit)

Comment: What's supposed to happen in between these two scripts?  Can you integrate the (un)subscribe calls into your main application, instead of trying to run them separately?